# Move wordpress from home web server to web server hosting account

Tags: wordpress, installation

I've installed and tested Wordpress configurations on my home server which I use as my test server.
Is it possible to upload everything, including Wordpress, from my home web server to my hosting account so it will work instantly there? 
Of course I need to change the database name, password, but that's about it.

thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to http://serverfault.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Nike's link is good, but also be aware they you may need to take extra steps when moving certain plugins, like CformsII, you will have to resetup your Widgets if you use any, and be sure to check your .htaccess file for any changes that you may have to make if you are using permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

For files, you should be able to upload your themes and plugins to the web host.

For the database, you can go into your local setup, Admin->Tools->Export. This will export your local WP settings, posts, pages, etc to a file.

Install WP on your host, then go to Admin->Tools->Import. Select the file from the previous step. Your hosted WP should now be the same as your local copy.