# wordpress page permalink is not working on local

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have wordpress website on server, created pages and that's working fine, but when I download wordpress files and DB on local and want to run with localhost, permalinks for pages are not working.

Comment: [WordPress codex: Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move wordpress from home web server to web server hosting account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704404/move-wordpress-from-home-web-server-to-web-server-hosting-account)

Answer (score 4):

It seems this is an old post, but this might help others that encounter same error.

Select:

Apache –> Apache Modules –> and that will display the lists of available modules.

Now just check `rewrite_module`.

source from [WordPress Custom Permalink not Working in Localhost](http://www.sutanaryan.com/wordpress/wordpress-custom-permalink-not-working-in-localhost/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when copying from one server to another, wordpress' permalinks goes a little screwy, try setting them back to default (using the admin panel) and then setting them again to your desired permalink structure (being sure to apply the changes each time).

Answer (score 0):

you need to go into the database and change a few options.

Goto your phpmyadmin installation and navigate to `wp-options` table. Change the `siteurl` and home options to your `localhost` address.

Wordpress needs these database tries to build your permalinks. If they are wrong, then it will direct your links to incorrect locations.

Comment: did that, also followed @Pekka comments, but still having issue. :(

Comment: added another answer that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fix this by doing the following:

1. Go to settings in your WordPress site.
2. click on permalinks ( You will see the URL structures of your newly configured WP site. (if it shows your original website values, go to settings-> general and set your local site URLs
3. Don't do any changes, just click on the Save button.
4. Refresh your local site and click on your page link or post.